# How to find some code to detect code packer?

Tags: compiler-construction, exe, detect, packer

I wanna check lots of execution files (*.exe) that made by packer or compilers.

So I need a library or anything like that which could tell me witch compiler or packer has made the *.exe files.

I have tried the exeinfo but it makes me lots of minute to wait becouse it works one by one.

Is there any program or library to handle that all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEiD](http://www.peid.info/) is your best choice.

If you need "a library" you could create a script that uses the supplied signature file. I think I saw a python script which did exactly this on a blog a while back, I lost the link though.